# HTML/CSS link scroll not scrolling to correct position

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm having trouble figuring out why my links are not scrolling to the correct position. They are scrolling to the section below where they should. I've looked at all the examples I could find to no avail.

```
 <div class="bottomarea">
 <div class="bottomareatitles">IDX Website Features</div>
 <div class="bottomareasubtitle">WeeboWeb real estate websites have all the tools you need to market yourself and grow your business online. Effective, professional designs that connect you with 32% more buyers and sellers. </div>
 <div id="iconcontainer">
    <a href="#effectivedesigns"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Effective Designs</div></a>
    <a href="#quicksetup"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-hourglass-half" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Quick Setup</div></a>
    <a href="#leadcapture"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Lead Capture</div></a>
    <a href="#mapsearch"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Map Search</div></a>
    <a href="#mobilefriendly"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Mobile Friendly</div></a>
    <a href="#socialmedia"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Social Media</div></a>
    <a href="#blogging"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Blogging</div></a>
    <a href="#branding"><div class="bottomareaicons"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Branding</div></a>
</div></div>

<div class="bottomsection">
  <div class="section">
  <h1><a id="effectivedesigns">Effective Designs</a></h1>
  <p>sample content</p></a>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
  <h1><a id="quicksetup">Quick Setup</a></h1>
  <p>sample content</p>
  </div>

 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="leadcapture">Lead Capture</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div>
 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="mapsearch">Map Search</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="mobilefriendly">Mobile Friendly</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="socialmedia">Social Media</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="blogging">Blogging</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div>

 <div class="section">
 <h1><a id="branding">Branding</a></h1>
 <p>sample content</p>
 </div></div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.bottomarea {display:block; width:100%;}
.bottomareatitles {text-align:center; margin-top:50px; font-size:26px; color:#000000; font-weight:350;}
.bottomareasubtitle {text-align:center; padding-top:20px; color: dimgrey; width:75%; margin:auto;}
.bottomareaicons {width:130px; display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align:center; margin-top:40px; color:#000000; font-size:16px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px;}
.bottomareaicons:hover {width:130px; display:inline-block; margin:auto; text-align:center; margin-top:40px; color:#000000; font-size:16px; background:#2584b8; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:10px;}
.bottomareaicons i {font-size:3.0em; padding-bottom:20px; color:#2584b8;}
.bottomareaicons:hover > i {font-size:3.0em; padding-bottom:20px; color:#ffffff;}
.iconcontainer {margin:auto; text-align:center;}
.bottomsection {margin-top:50px;}
.bottomsection .section h1 {text-align:center;}
.bottomsection .section p {text-align:center;}
```

You can see a live example of whats happening here: https://www.weeboweb.com/idx-websites/

I'm attempting to just use css to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. This has had me a bit baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by simply adding padding-top:100px; inline to each section element. I did it inline to make sure that the section element doesn't interfere with anything else. I also don't mind the additional space as this particular page warrants it when I finish the design. I don't feel this is the best answer to solving this problem in the future, but in this case it fixed it for me. I also moved the a element outside of the h1 element. You can see ti working here now at https://weeboweb.com.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually scrolling "below", it's scrolling to where it should. The problem is that area is being covered up by your top navigation which stays fixed to the top of the screen. You need to account for this with your spacing, or don't have a fixed top nav.

Comment: I understand that. I understand it's going up under the header. The problem is that I am not sure of the best way to compensate for the fixed header here and changing the way the header is done really isn't an option for me. Any useful suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you forgot to compensate for your header. The page is scrolling so that the element is at the top of the page... Behind the header.

There are several solutions [here in a CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/) article that can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Right. I can see that. I understand it's going up under the header. I tried the css tricks and I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I was unable to get it to work. The problem is that I am not sure of the best way to compensate for the fixed header here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: Need to correct the navbar implementation before looking at the bookmark issue

First, add `padding-top` equal to your header height (76px) to your body.

```
body {
    padding-top: 76px;
}
```

Next, remove the `min-height: 76px`, make it `0`. from your `header`. Move the `position: fixed` from your `#main-nav` to your `header` element (if possible, else it is fine to be on `#main-nav`. Add `top:0` to the `#main-nav`

```
#main-nav {
   top: 0;
}
```

This should solve your problem.

EDIT:
You are using bootstrap, but not using bootstrap navbar-fixed-to-top solution. please refer this - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Also note this at the same place in the bootstrap documentation

> Body padding required
>   The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the . Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

`body { padding-top: 70px; }`
Make sure to include this after the core Bootstrap CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately it created several other issues. My header is now halfway invisible at the top of the screen. I can see the text behind it. and the body is still dropped down. Also, it's not scrolling to the right position now. It's probably being affected by other elements.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not getting it. The header is already fixed to the top. Adding the navbar fixed top just moves it up a bit further. When I add padding to the top of the body, ALL of my content is skewed. I'm starting to think I should just quit and use jquery?

Comment: When I add the padding to the body, and use navtop to move the header to the top, I can see the body moving down. However, I also still notice when I click  the links that this has 0 effect on where the link moves too. Its still in the same place.